# Sort by date with set data in php/wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type "books" and in it there is a custom_field called "publication date". The data in this field typically looks like this "November 2014" or "July 2013".

There's already a lot of books with these values added in and I need a way to sort the posts by this publication date, instead of manually changing the publication date to a better value.

**Publication date is not to the published date of the post.**

Thanks!

Comment: You need to write a function, what replace those dates to a sortable format.

Comment: or you can sort this in php using strtotime on publication date field, but this is just temporally solution

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help:

```
   $args = array( 
      'post_type' => 'books',
      'meta_key' = 'publication_date',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value',
      'order'=>'ASC' 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert the meta value to date type first and then only sort. The following code does that for you

```
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'books',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order'=>'ASC',
        'meta_query'    =>  array(
            array(
                'key'   =>  'publication-date',
                'type'  =>  'DATE'
            )
        ),
    );
```